# URLRewriting.net and IIS 7 Problem

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, umbraco

net 2.0/umbraco 4.0.3 website hosted in IIS6 with a couple of url rewrites using http://urlrewriting.net/  .. 
We just moved the site to IIS 7/classic pool and the URL rewrites stopped working.. can anyone give a hint of what might be the issue as we are trying for sometime without any luck!

Regards,
Anz

Comment: 404.. The error is only for extensionless URLs.. rewrites to .aspx extension is working fine..

Comment: i think if the version of umbraco is 4.0.3,it requires .net framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mahesh Umbraco 4.0.3 only requires .NET 3.5 (read: .NET 2.0 with AJAX libraries, which are included in the distribution).

@Anz, best things to check for are:

1. Have you added the wildcard ISAPI handler to the site for Classic mode? For extensionless URLs to work, you must add a wildcard handler to the site, which then points to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll. This applies to IIS6 and IIS7 sites in Classic mode (IIS6 only has classic mode).
2. In Integrated mode, however, this isn't required... so you could try switching your application pool to Integrated mode and see if this works.
3. Check your application pool's identity. Sometimes the site won't load components properly because the identity of the application pool can't access them. In IIS7, you have a new principle called ApplicationPoolIdentity, which creates a new user **just** for that app-pool, in the format "IIS APPPOOL\". If your app-pool has it's Identity property set to ApplicationPoolIdentity, you need to grant read/write/modify access on it by going to the folder, right-clicking and hitting Properties, switching to Security, click "Edit", click "Add...", type "IIS APPPOOL\" (without quotes, **with all spaces**), click OK. Set the "Modify" attribute against this user, click Apply, click Close.

HTH,

Benjamin

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I checked and the Identity is set to Network pool.. it looks like the wildcard mapping has the issue.. cos redirects with extension work fine.. I tried the solution explained here and the wildcard mapping worked but couldn't make the StaticFiles work.. i lost all the styles.. http://improve.dk/archive/2006/12/11/making-url-rewriting-on-iis7-work-like-iis6.aspx

Comment: Hi Anz, IIS7 is a little strange because it "orders" the ISAPI extensions. Go into ISAPI Extensions in IIS7 for the site, go to "View Ordered List", then move StaticFile to just above your wildcard mapping. Then try reload the site. This *should* do it IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

I had upgraded the server from 32-bit Windows to 64-bit Windows.

Needed to check 'allow 32-bit applications' on the app pools.